# Scopes in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, scopeinterface

I know that in magento config, we have 3 scopes: Global (default), website and store view.

But when I take a look at ScopeInterface, I see 6 scope types

```
interface ScopeInterface
{
    /**#@+
     * Scope types
     */
    const SCOPE_STORES = 'stores';
    const SCOPE_GROUPS   = 'groups';
    const SCOPE_WEBSITES = 'websites';

    const SCOPE_STORE   = 'store';
    const SCOPE_GROUP   = 'group';
    const SCOPE_WEBSITE = 'website';
    /**#@-*/
}
```

When I look at `core_config_data` table in the databases, I only see STORES scope, not STORE. But when people want to get config data via `ScopeConfigInterface`, they normally use SCOPE_STORE (not SCOPE_STORES)

[image]

Note: I use WriterInterface to save my config and I want to save it at store scope. Should I use STORES or STORE?

Comment: Do you want to perform the extension on store level or website level?

Comment: Do you want to function of your extension on store level, right?

Comment: Yes, when set config I use STORES and when getting the config I use STORE. But I don't know why, just see others did that